# Unhandled exceptions with Java scheduled executors

Tags: java, exception, multithreading, executor

I have the following issue and I would like to know what exactly happens. I am using Java's [ScheduledExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to run a task every five minutes. It works very well. Executors completely changed the way I do thread programming in Java.

Now, I browsed Java Doc for information about what would be the behavior in case the scheduled task fails with an unhandled exception, but couldn't find anything.

Is the next scheduled task still going to run? If there is an unhandled exception, the scheduled executor stops scheduling task? Can anyone point to information regarding this simple issue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Javadoc of both `scheduleAtFixedRate` and `scheduleWithFixedDelay` says "If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed." I don't find that to be exactly crystal clear, but it seems to be saying that if your `run` method throws any kind of exception, then the scheduler will effectively drop that task. Any other tasks running via that scheduler should not be affected. It shouldn't be hard to test what it actually does...

Cancellation of the task may not necessarily be a bad thing. If the run method throws a `RuntimeException`, it's probably got a bug somewhere, and the state of the system is unknown. But at minimum I would advise catching `RuntimeException` in your run method, and logging the full stack trace at SEVERE. You may want to then rethrow to cancel the task, depending on the circumstances. But either way you'll need the logging to have a fighting chance of working out what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I didn't see that in API Doc.

Comment: A quick browse of the source for ThreadPoolExecutor (atop which the STPE is implemented) suggests that RuntimeExceptions will be neatly caught and reported back via the ScheduledFuture, but that they will also cause the worker thread to terminate.  The TPE will notice this worker thread termination and spin up a new replacement, if necessary.  See runWorker() and processWorkerExit() in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor in the JDK sources, or on Doug Lea's site.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using `scheduleAtFixedRate()` or `scheduleAtFixedDelay()`, and your task bails out with an exception, that task will not be rescheduled.  However, other independent tasks should continue to execute as expected. (See [API Docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))).  If you care that this has happened, you can grab ahold of the `ScheduledFuture` that is returned and call the `get()` method.  If the underlying task tosses an exception, you'll get it thrown out of the `get()` method, wrapped in an `ExecutionException`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. +1. Too bad I can't accept two answers as "the answer". Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, man, Lachlan beat me to the punch... rules is rules.  ;-)

Comment: Strange..my successive task stop too.

Answer (score 3):

This man had the same problem.

http://code.nomad-labs.com/2011/12/09/mother-fk-the-scheduledexecutorservice/

His solution is to catch `Exception` inside the runnable and re throw an `RuntimeException`:

```
try {
       theRunnable.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // LOG IT HERE!!!
       System.err.println("error in executing: " + theRunnable + ". It will no longer be run!");
       e.printStackTrace();

       // and re throw it so that the Executor also gets this error so that it can do what it would
       // usually do
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the API doesn't define any specific exception handling mechanism. I.e. uncaught exception just pops through the thread frames and eventually is being logged to stderr.

I see that you can exploit the following exception handling strategies:

- define handler at the class of the task which objects are submitted to thread pool;
- provide your own [ThreadFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) implementation to thread pool that initializes default handler via [setUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) or [ThreadGroup's uncaughtException()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable));

Comment: I dont think these exceptions are logged.