# How to schedule a functional to execute at interval

Tags: java

i am trying to schedule a function to `clear` the `variable` in java. if I  remove `AES.keyMap.clear();` following code works. I can see continuous `print` messages at given interval. However, as soon as I either put `AES.keyMap.clear()` or a method which clears that variable, `task1` is being invoked only once.

```java
public class Task {
    private static int count = 0;
static Runnable task1 = () -> {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Trying to clear cache count : " + count);
        try{
            AES.resetKeyMap();
        }catch (UnsupportedOperationException e){
//            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    };
    public static void clearCache(){
         final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
         scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Task.clearCache();
    }
}
```

**AES.java**

```java
public class AES {
    private static Map<String, Map<String,String>> keyMap = new HashMap<>();

     public static String getKeyFromKeyManager(String databaseName, String schemaName, String tableName, String colName){
        ClassifyFields c = new ClassifyFields("classification.props");
        String key = null;
        try {
            if(keyMap.isEmpty()){
                logger.info("keymap is empty calling getColumnsWithKeys to initialize it");
                keyMap.put(databaseName+schemaName+tableName, c.getColumnsWithKeys(databaseName, schemaName, tableName));
                Task.clearCache();
            }else{
                logger.info("keymap is not empty");
            }
            key = keyMap.get(databaseName+schemaName+tableName).get(colName);
        } catch (ClassificationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            key=null;
        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getStackTrace());
        }
        logger.info(keyMap);
        logger.info("key: :"+key);
        return key;
    }

    public static void resetKeyMap() {
        keyMap.clear();
    }
}
```

**Update:**
The problem is `getKeyFromKeyManager`. If I comment all the interaction with `keyMap` I able to call the `resetKeyMap` method at interval.

Comment: Did you check if any exception happens on clear ()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled exceptions with Java scheduled executors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660834/unhandled-exceptions-with-java-scheduled-executors)

Comment: @tkruse I checked. it throw `UnsupportedOperationException` . I tried to catch it and `Exception`. I tried to re throw `RuntimeException`. However nothing is working. it just gets stuck after first call

Comment: For help with exceptions add the stacktrace to the question. Also consider asking for help in java chat